# Truly removing the resize handle from a <textarea>

Tags: html, css, textarea

How do you actually fully remove the resize handle from a `<textarea>` element? Setting `resize:none;` only seems to hide the resize, but does not allow the height to be reduced past where the resize handle would be as seen in the images below. This can easily be reproduced by creating a `<textarea>` with no set height property and observing that the height of the textarea does not change when the resize handle is hidden. I am looking for a way to ensure that the textarea will be 1em high when there is only one line of text.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. You can either apply this as an inline style property like so:

```
<textarea style="resize: none;"></textarea>
```

2. For specific changes:

to disable all:

```
textarea { resize: none; }
```

only vertical resize:

```
textarea { resize: vertical; }
```

only horizontal resize:

```
textarea { resize: horizontal; }
```

disable vertical and horizontal with limit:

```
textarea { resize: horizontal; max-width: 400px; min-width: 200px; }
```

disable horizontal and vertical with limit:

```
textarea { resize: vertical; max-height: 300px; min-height: 200px; }
```

Comment: Hey, this isn't what I was asking about. I know that you can hide the resizer by using `resize:none;` but I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the extra height that comes with the resizer, even if it was hidden, as per the images in OP.